# When creating a Heroku Add-On for a multi-tenant service, how do you provision multiple Heroku applications to a single tenant?

Tags: heroku, multi-tenant, add-on

[Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com) is a multi-tenant cloud Identity Management service that we want to make available to Heroku users as a Heroku add-on.

Like Heroku, Stormpath has the ability to represent one or more applications per customer (where 'customer' is synonymous with 'tenant').

For example, just as a Heroku customer can deploy one or more applications to Heroku (testing, staging, production, etc), a Stormpath customer (tenant) can register one or more applications that they would like Stormpath to secure.

In this sense, Stormpath's model and Heroku's model appear to be identical for this 1-to-Many (customer-to-applications) relationship.

Here's my question:

When a Heroku customer adds the Stormpath add on to multiple applications, how do we ensure that the applications are associated with the same Stormpath tenant?

During [add-on provisioning](https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/technical/build/provisioning), is there a way the add-on implementation can get a Heroku customer's unique tenant identifier that is common across all of their Heroku applications? For example, a unique Heroku tenant id or Heroku tenant owner email address?

The implementation logic would work as follows:

- Does the owner of the Heroku app being provisioned have a Stormpath tenant?

  - No: Create the Stormpath tenant then associate the app with the new tenant.
  - Yes: Associate the app to the owner's existing Stormpath tenant.

Answer (score 0):

When Heroku sends you the provision request you'll get a JSON blob something [like this](https://addons.heroku.com/provider/resources/technical/reference/api-spec):

```
{
  "heroku_id": "app123@heroku.com",
  "plan": "basic",
  "region": "amazon-web-services::us-east-1",
  "callback_url": "https://api.heroku.com/vendor/apps/app123%40heroku.com",
  "options": {}
}
```

You could use that `heroku_id` to find the user identifier through Heroku's [AppInfo API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-on-app-info#get-app-info).

Comment: `heroku_id` is _not_ the Heroku user identifier.  It is the identifier of an individual application provisioned in Heroku.  A Heroku customer ('tenant') can have many apps.

Comment: @Les You're quite right. Amended to show how you _can_ get the _user_ identifier.

Comment: thanks very much for the follow up - unfortunately, the Heroku documentation indicates that the App owner's email address could change, at which point it ceases to be an immutable identifier.  So I can't use this to associate every application to a known Tenant (if the user changes their email address, all new apps under that email will have to be created in to a new Tenant - not desirable at all).  I wish Heroku would just offer a proper unique immutable API.  Very strange that they don't...